# Java RMI tutorial compile time error - Interface not found

Tags: java, rmi

I'm following a basic Java RMI tutorial for a distributed system here: http://people.cs.aau.dk/~bnielsen/DS-E08/Java-RMI-Tutorial/

I'm having a problem with compiling my Server implementation.

The error is as follows:

```
RMIServer.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol: class ServerInterface
public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface {
                                                          ^
1 error
```

This is my server implementation:

```
package rmiTutorial; 
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject; 
import java.rmi.*; 

public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface { 

  private String myString = " "; 

  //Default constructor 
  public RMIServer() throws RemoteException { 
    super(); 
  } 

  //inherited methods 
  public void setString(String s) throws RemoteException { 
    this.myString =s; 
  } 

  public String getString() throws RemoteException{ 
    return myString; 
  } 

  //main: instantiate and register server object 
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
    try{ 
      String name = "RMIServer"; 
      System.out.println("Registering as: \"" + name + "\""); 
      RMIServer serverObject = new RMIServer(); 
      Naming.rebind(name, serverObject); 
      System.out.println(name + " ready..."); 
    } catch (Exception registryEx){ 
      System.out.println(registryEx); 
    } 
  }  
}
```

ServerInterface:

```
package rmiTutorial;                                                                                
import java.rmi.*;

public interface ServerInterface {

  public String getString() throws RemoteException;
  public void setString(String s) throws RemoteException;

}
```

The RMIServer class and the ServerInterface are both in the same package.
I've followed the tutorial exactly, so I don't really understand how I've managed to break it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Tori

Comment: How are you compiling these ?

Comment: You have to first compile ServerInterface then RMIServer

Comment: Originally I compiled ServerInterface, then attempted to compile RMIServer separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're compiling these separately. The tutorial isn't clear on this, but you need to compile these together (in the simplest case):

```
javac rmiTutorial/RMIServer.java rmiTutorial/ServerInterface.java
```

(including other appropriate flags as necessary - libs, classpath etc.).

You need to compile the two together such that the compiler can find the `ServerInterface` when it builds the `RMIServer`. You *can* compile the `ServerInterface` first, but then you need to compile the `RMIServer` with a suitable classpath reference such that it can find the interface.

Comment: Thanks very much! Compiled straight away that time! Just for clarification, why is this the case?

Comment: Answer amended to answer your subsequent question

Comment: Eh? Compiling the server class will compile the interface in this case. I've been doing this for fifteen years. It only fails if the directories and packages don't agree.